# using string methods to count words

Tags: java

I am struggling with the below assignment:

assignment q:
using methods from the string class, write a program that will count the number of words which are separated by blanks in a string. For simplicity, use strings without punctuation or other white space characters(tabs, newlines etc). Use a JTextArea to allow the user to enter the text and allow the text area to scroll if necessary. when the user clicks a button to count the words , the total number of words counted is displayed in a textbox that cannot be modified by the user.

now my problem is that i am not getting the counted number to display in the un-editable textbox.
i also have the problem where the cusrsor is showing in the middle of the input screen instead of at the top.

please can you point me in the right direction.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WordCounter extends  JFrame implements ActionListener
{

//Construct a panel for the fields and buttons
JPanel fieldPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

//Construct labels and text boxes
    JTextField screen = new JTextField(1);
JLabel wordCount = new JLabel("  Word Count = ");
JTextField words = new JTextField(3);


//Construct button
JButton countButton = new JButton("Count Words");

    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    WordCounter f = new WordCounter();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(500,200);
    f.setTitle("Word Counter");
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setLocation(200,200);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public static int getWordCount(String screen)
{
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < screen.length(); i++)
    {
        if (screen.charAt(i) == ' ')
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public WordCounter()
{
    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout((new BorderLayout()));
    fieldPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));

    //add rows to panels
    fieldPanel.add(screen);

    //add button to panel
    buttonPanel.add(countButton);
    buttonPanel.add(wordCount);
    buttonPanel.add(words);

    //add panels to frame
    c.add(fieldPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    c.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //add functionality to button
    countButton.addActionListener(this);



    addWindowListener(
        new WindowAdapter()
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                int answer = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Are you sure you want to exit?", "File Submission",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (answer == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                    System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    );
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
}
```

}

Comment: a little offtopic: use String.split(" ") instead of your getWordCount-loop

Answer (score 0):

To display the word count, you must modify your `actionPerformed` method like so:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    words.setText(String.valueOf(getWordCount(screen.getText())));
}
```

And also your method for counting words produces incorrect result if the entered text doesn't end with a space. You could modify your `getWordCount` method for example like this to get correct word count:

```
public static int getWordCount(String screen)
{
    String[] words = screen.split("\\s+");
    return words.length;
}
```

And for your second problem: your cursor displays in the center because `JTextField` is a single line input. Use `JTextArea` instead. It is after all specified in your question that you should use it:

```
JTextArea screen = new JTextArea();
```

Answer (score 0):

try it:

public static int getWordCount(String screen)
{
    int count = 0;

```
string[] words = screen.split(' ');

count = words.Length;
return count;
```

}